# Load balancing where ressources are available

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, autoscaling, kubernetes-ingress

I would like to know how could i setup a load balancer at the kubernetes level so my services points to the pods that has the more ram/cpu ressources available and not randomly.

It would be co-existing with a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler.

As of today i have an ingress pointing to my NodePort service

It would be better if it could work localy with minikube without needing to be on a cloud provider.

If not, im using OVH as my Kubernetes cloud provider.

Thanks for any infos

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a copy of https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/6478/210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q**: services points to the pods that has the more ram/cpu ressources
>   available

There is no such feature in Kubernetes at the moment.

But you can switch kube-proxy to [ipvs](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/) mode and it allows you to use the following balancing algorithm:

> - rr: round-robin
> - lc: least connection
> - dh: destination hashing
> - sh: source hashing
> - sed: shortest expected delay
> - nq: never queue

Calico also [supports](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/usage/enabling-ipvs) it.